# Need suggestion as in is it better to use a scroll view or a listview in my case.

Tags: android

I have an application I am working on, its a simple app consisting of media playback functionality of some spiritual chants. While the chants play in background I am highlighting part of the lyrics (in Blocks) and bringing it to the top of the container layout, however the lyrics is in two languages and is lengthy, as of now I have put textviews inside a scroll view  but this is proving to be tedious. I want suggestion as in if using a scroll view is feasible or should I use a list view? If I use a listview I need to create an array of strings in Hindi and English. Can anyone suggest me something viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have suggested you ListView, because ListView is fast as compare to ScrollView, Whatever rows you can see ListView only inflate as much rows at one time, means no all the data are inflated at a time. When you scroll it will inflate more and more. You need to create Array is quite simple. But for better efficieny and speed I suggested you to use ListView.

And you will get benefit on layout as well.

Comment: Hmm then I have to manage to highlight the first block at the center of the listview too. So means that at the start, the first row should be at the center of the list view then subsequently it will move up, because ill place the highlight block at the center.

Comment: Yeah, when you run app first time, put one row at center, when new block comes, make listview notify so it will automatically moves up and newer one at the center. You have to do design it like as per your need.

Comment: accept the answer, if you find useful, so other people can take benefit of it.

Comment: Definately will do, I am just waiting if I get more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with answer above.

> Hmm then I have to manage to highlight the first block at the center
>   of the listview too. So means that at the start, the first row should
>   be at the center of the list view then subsequently it will move up,
>   because ill place the highlight block at the center

You have to calculate how many rows are currently showing on device. Then add rowcount/2 of empty strings at the beginning of your array and append same to the end.
So users will see something like this:

> empty row
>
> empty row
>
> empty row
>
> **LALALALALLALALA**
>
> lalalala i love you
>
> lalalala don't leave me
>
> etc

Then list scrolls while song plays and there will be no empty text for some time.
After that, when song finishes users will see something like that:

> etc
>
> lalalala don't leave me
>
> lalalala i love you
>
> **LALALALALLALALA**
>
> empty row
>
> empty row
>
> empty row

Comment: Good, I will follow this!